# Why does React Native DateTimePicker not render when I pull it out into a helper function?

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I have two different behaviors/component structures for the DateTimePicker (one for Android and one for iOS). Explicitly using the DateTimePicker in both of these situations works, however, when I pull out the DateTimePicker into a helper function (to avoid duplicate code), the picker doesn't render. Why is this?

Example of my code without explicitly using the DateTimePicker (Note: This does not work, however, when I explicitly put the DateTimePicker component instead of the helper function, then the rendering works):

```
// A boolean value to determine when to show the date picker
const [showPicker, setShowPicker] = useState<boolean>(true);

// Helper function that returns the DateTimePicker component
const getDatePicker = () => {
  <DateTimePicker
  ...
   />
};

// Return value of the main component
return Platform.OS === "android" ? (
  <>{showPicker && getDatePicker()}</>
) : (
  <CustomModal>
    {showPicker && getDatePicker()}
  </CustomModal>
);
```

Comment: const getDatePicker = () => (
  <DateTimePicker
  ...
   />
)

Comment: you are not returning the date picker from your helper function maybe?

Comment: @RizwanAtta Ohmygosh, I think you're right! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hie @geriblee hope you are having a good day.

Believe you are missing the return statement for the helper function

**instead of doing this:**

```
// Helper function that returns the DateTimePicker component

const getDatePicker = () => {
  <DateTimePicker
  ...
   />
};
```

**do this:**

```
const getDatePicker = () => <DateTimePicker ... />
```